# Does an Amazon EC2 EBS root volume snaphot include mounted tmpfs filesystems such as /run?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm expecting the answer to be no but I can't quite reason out why not.

Answer (score 2):

Because tmpfs filesystems exist only in RAM, not on the disk.

Thus, your snapshot will contain only the mount point itself, not any data that happens to be stored within it on the running system.